# How to add special id for every item in the list

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wp-list-categories

Hi I have a sidebar in my wordpress site based on this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/).

I want that every item in the category list will have a id in html for himself.
And if there are more than one lists the numbers of the item will not repeat.

For ex.:

first list:

- id="item_1"
- id="item_2"

second list:

- id="item_3"
- id="item_4"

something like this...

> **Right know the plugin didnt do id for the items**

THE CODE:

**The code of the plugin is here:**

```
<?php /*   Plugin Name: List category posts   Plugin URI: https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts   Description: List Category Posts allows you to list posts from a category into a post/page using the [catlist] shortcode. This shortcode accepts a category name or id, the order in which you want the posts to display, and the number of posts to display. You can use [catlist] as many times as needed with different arguments. Usage: [catlist argument1=value1 argument2=value2].   Version: 0.49.1   Author: Fernando Briano   Author URI: http://picandocodigo.net/

  Text Domain:   list-category-posts   Domain Path:   /languages/

  Copyright 2008-2014  Fernando Briano  (email : fernando@picandocodigo.net)

  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by   the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or   any later version.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the   GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software   Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

load_plugin_textdomain( 'list-category-posts', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );

include 'include/ListCategoryPostsWidget.php'; include 'include/options.php'; require_once 'include/CatListDisplayer.php';

class ListCategoryPosts{   /**    * Gets the shortcode parameters and instantiate plugin objects    * @param $atts    * @param $content   
*/   static function catlist_func($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
                             'id' => '0',
                             'name' => '',
                             'orderby' => 'date',
                             'order' => 'desc',
                             'numberposts' => '',
                             'date' => 'no',
                             'date_tag' => '',
                             'date_class' =>'',
                             'dateformat' => get_option('date_format'),
                             'date_modified' => '',
                             'date_modified_tag' => '',
                             'date_modified_class' => '',
                             'author' => 'no',
                             'author_posts_link' => 'no',
                             'author_tag' =>'',
                             'author_class' => '',
                             'author_posts' => '',
                             'template' => 'default',
                             'excerpt' => 'no',
                             'excerpt_size' => '55',
                             'excerpt_strip' => 'yes',
                             'excerpt_overwrite' => 'no',
                             'excerpt_tag' =>'',
                             'excerpt_class' =>'',
                             'exclude' => '0',
                             'excludeposts' => '0',
                             'offset' => '0',
                             'tags' => '',
                             'exclude_tags' => '',
                             'currenttags' => '',
                             'content' => 'no',
                             'content_tag' => '',
                             'content_class' => '',
                             'display_id' => 'no',
                             'catlink' => 'no',
                             'catname' => 'no',
                             'catlink_string' => '',
                             'catlink_tag' =>'',
                             'catlink_class' => '',
                             'comments' => 'no',
                             'comments_tag' => '',
                             'comments_class' => '',
                             'starting_with' => '',
                             'thumbnail' => 'no',
                             'thumbnail_size' => 'thumbnail',
                             'thumbnail_class' => '',
                             'title_tag' => '',
                             'title_class' => '',
                             'title_limit' => '0',
                             'post_type' => '',
                             'post_status' => '',
                             'post_parent' => '0',
                             'post_suffix' => '',
                             'show_protected' => 'no',
                             'class' => 'lcp_catlist',
                             'customfield_name' => '',
                             'customfield_value' =>'',
                             'customfield_display' =>'',
                             'customfield_display_name' =>'',
                             'customfield_orderby' =>'',
                             'customfield_tag' => '',
                             'customfield_class' => '',
                             'taxonomy' => '',
                             'categorypage' => '',
                             'category_count' => '',
                             'morelink' => '',
                             'morelink_class' => '',
                             'morelink_tag' => '',
                             'posts_morelink' => '',
                             'posts_morelink_class' => '',
                             'year' => '',
                             'monthnum' => '',
                             'search' => '',
                             'link_target' => '',
                             'pagination' => 'no',
                             'pagination_next' => '>>',
                             'pagination_prev' => '<<',
                             'no_posts_text' => "",
                             'instance' => '0'
                           ), $atts);
    if( $atts['numberposts'] == ''){
      $atts['numberposts'] = get_option('numberposts');
    }
    if( $atts['pagination'] == 'yes'){
      lcp_pagination_css();
    }
    $catlist_displayer = new CatListDisplayer($atts);
    return $catlist_displayer->display();   } }

add_shortcode( 'catlist', array('ListCategoryPosts', 'catlist_func') );

function lpc_meta($links, $file) {   $plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);

  if ($file == $plugin):
    return array_merge(
      $links,
      array( sprintf('<a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/">%s</a>',
__('How to use','list-category-posts')) ),
      array( sprintf('<a href="http://picandocodigo.net/programacion/wordpress/list-category-posts-wordpress-plugin-english/#support">%s</a>',
__('Donate','list-category-posts')) ),
      array( sprintf('<a href="https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts">%s</a>',
__('Fork on Github','list-category-posts')) )
    );   endif;

  return $links; }

add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', 'lpc_meta', 10, 2 );

function lcp_pagination_css(){   if ( @file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lcp_paginator.css' ) ):
    $css_file = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lcp_paginator.css';   elseif ( @file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/lcp_paginator.css' ) ):
    $css_file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/lcp_paginator.css';   else:
    $css_file = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . basename( __DIR__ ) . '/lcp_paginator.css';   endif;

  wp_enqueue_style( 'lcp_paginator', $css_file); }

/**  * TO-DO:
- Pagination * DONE - Need to add "page" text
- Add Older Posts at bottom of List Category Post page
- Simpler template system
- Exclude child categories  */
```

Comment: `specific items ` Which items?? post your **HTML**. If they have some sort of indentifier, such as a class, then you can write some CSS, and put it in the stylesheet.

Comment: `IDs` should be *unique*, so give it a class, and then you can do `.hello1 { color:red }` in your `.css` file for example.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that the plugin generates for the categories list.

Comment: You can view the page source and copy the HTML for the sidebar.

Comment: You will most likely have to modify the plugin code. Although if you add the HTML here, then we can all see if the plugin already adds classes for each item, based on the page name or something like that.

Comment: Can you add the HTML that the plugin renders on the webpage in the sidebar.

Comment: I edit the question,so delete your comments for fresh start ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the # on the stylesheet is used for ID.  If you create a style using #mystyle{} (or whatever) and assign it to the items then that will give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: Use a pseudo selector class to target specific list items based on the parent ID.

Comment: I think just using a class sounds more appropriate for what he's talking about.  @user3706524 read some w3schools.com and get familiar with using CSS classes and IDs